# how to create dynamic hierachal dropdowns for woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

My product categories have a maximum of 4 tiers, as well as having a [traditional menu](http://jsfiddle.net/YXkUT/1783/), I would like to create a menu using 4 `<select>` elements which options change dynamically depending on the previous selection.

it would look something like [this.](http://jsfiddle.net/YXkUT/1787/)

This does not need to filter the products! it is purely to create a redirect link.

I cant seem to find a plugin that does this, i've seen far more complicated filtering plugins but none seem to meet my needs.  so any help on how to achive this would be great.

Its particularly the PHP wp_query side of things I am struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_product_dropdown_categories/

just open This link and watch ....
Here is the code for your Dropdwon for categories 

 or just use this code :-----------------

 add_shortcode( 'product_categories_dropdown', 
                          'woo_product_categories_dropdown' );
        function woo_product_categories_dropdown( $atts ) {
       extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                   'count'         => '0',
                    'hierarchical'  => '0',
                          'orderby'         => ''
                           ), $atts));

            ob_start();

         $c = $count;
             $h = $hierarchical;
            $o = ( isset( $orderby ) && $orderby != '' ) ? $orderby :  
                             'order';

            // Stuck with this until a fix for     
            http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13258
        woocommerce_product_dropdown_categories( $c, $h, 0, $o );
    ?>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            /* <![CDATA[ */
                var product_cat_dropdown =    
             document.getElementById("dropdown_product_cat");
    function onProductCatChange() {
        if (     
     product_cat_dropdown.options[product_cat_dropdown.selectedIndex].value 
        !=='' ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?     

                     product_cat="+product_cat_dropdown.options[product_cat_dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
         }
      }
    product_cat_dropdown.onchange = onProductCatChange;
         /* ]]> */
             </script>
       <?php

      return ob_get_clean();

         }
```